# Using two jQuery versions on the same page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making my project in twitter bootstrap. I am using a file upload script extension with jQuery. This plugin is already developed. I just ave to place it.

But bootstrap is developed for some other jquery version and this plugin is developed with 1.5.1 version of jQuery.

I am planning to not to import the 1.5.1 version. Will it create an problem?

Comment: This **IS NOT** a 'version control'.

Comment: _I am planning to not to import the 1.5.1 version. Will it create an problem?_ We do not know what jQ features you have used in the plugin. Just replace the jQuery with the newest version and check if your plugin works or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include both the js files..you can use jquery js files of multiple versions by using `noConflict` ..there is no problem with this

```
 <!-- load jQuery1.5 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_5 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>

    <!-- load jQuery 1.9 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.9.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_9= $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
```

Comment: Remember that you can't use the "dot" in a variable name.

Comment: @MarcoK..yep i just edited..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use JQuery 1.9, there is a JQuery Migrate plugin which might be useful.

It is designed for when you are migrating to a newer JQuery version.  I have used it in the past, it adds the old features again and will give you a warning if you ever make use of a function which is depreciated.

This way you will know if the file upload plugin makes use of depreciated code and could possibly update it.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/